# Percentage execution for login and checkout operation

Tags: testing, jmeter, blazemeter

I am conducting a performance testing where i have a scenario where I have to execute home page , login, product catalogue and checkout operation for a ecommerce site. But I am doing the login operation 40% of the time and checkout 20%. how can i tell jmeter to execute checkout only for loged in user??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) to `control how often samplers below it are executed`. You can use the option `Percent executions`

Include two transaction controllers as given in the following picture.

[image]

Set 40 in the first Throughput controller and 50 in the second Throughput controller.

[image]

You can see the distribution of the executions in the summary report.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve the options are in:

1. [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
2. [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)
3. [Weighted Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)